# Need details about install4j error.log file

Tags: install4j

We have noticed that an error.log file sometimes gets created in the same directory as the installer.exe.
Can I get thedetails about when exactly the file is created and what exactly it contains ? Will it have say, the details of unhandled exceptions in the installer code, or will it have any other errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error.log file contains the output of stderr. It is only crated when the first character is written to stderr. The installer should not print anything on stderr, so this may be a bug.